# HTML and CSS files are the same but styles are applied differently between projects

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two different repositories for the same project I am working on locally on my machine. One of the pages I am working on is showing different styling on one of the elements between these repos even though the HTML, CSS, and JS files that pertain to this web page are the exact same. I have confirmed this using WinMerge. It appears that the bootstrap class `card-img-overlay` is the culprit. Here is an example of how the styles are behaving differently:

This is how it should be behaving, I removed the other classes I used just to show the issue with this class specifically: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UMzs.jpg

Chrome lists the `card-img-overlay` styles as such:

```
.card-img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1.25rem;
```

This is how it is behaving in the other repo, as you can see, the card-img-overlay is not applied over the whole card, just at the bottom, and with margins instead of padding https://i.stack.imgur.com/y45un.jpg

Chrome lists the `card-img-overlay` styles for this one as:

```
.card-img-overlay {
    min-height: 2.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10.9375em;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0.0625rem;
    margin: 0.0625rem 1.5625rem 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
```

I have checked to make sure both projects are using the same version of bootstrap, and they are both using the same 4.3.1 bootstrap cdn links. I have checked every file that is related to this web page between the projects in WinMerge and they are all identical (the HTML file itself, the CSS file associated with it, even a javascript file the page uses that doesn't even effect the styling). I have tested the different projects in both Chrome and Firefox, and the differences I have pointed out related to the card-img-overlay still persist, so it's not a browser issue either. I finally decided to just copy and paste the files from the correct version over to the incorrect version and overwrite them in the file explorer just to make sure they are the same but they still have different styles when being served from the different projects.

Here is the element that contains these different styles:

```
<div class="image-block card border-0" onclick="getProjectSTAAR()">
    <img src="assets/img/spotlight-page/STAARspotlight-graphic-03.jpg" class="card-img spotlight-img-group" alt="" />
    <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end justify-content-center">
        <p class="overlay-background  text-center fnt-goth-med">
            TEST NAME
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

These cards are contained in a group of 5 representing one bootstrap carousel item.

Here's any custom CSS contained in this element as well:

```
.image-block {
  max-height: 11.625rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*keeping all cards same dimensions*/
.spotlight-img-group {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 10em;
  min-width: 10em;
}

.overlay-background {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}
```

The overlay should just be a rectangular white box with the text contained in the middle at the bottom of the card, but the incorrect version is invisible completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After combing through everything I could think of I decided to just copy the `card-img-overlay` class from the Bootstrap 4.3.1 source code and overwrite the properties that were being forcibly applied to the element. Namely Margins and a background-color. The class looks like this:

```
.card-img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

To all who may find this answer in the future, it's not a proper solution, but at this point I've given up. Good luck.